# In React Testing Library, when having two fireEvent.change on two different elements, the second element is not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

When updating the value of a second element using React Testing Library using fireEvent.change, the value of the second element is not updated. I'm running @testing-library/react@12.1.5. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  render,
  screen,
  fireEvent,
  prettyDOM,
  logRoles,
  act,
} from "@testing-library/react";
import MyComponent from "../../components/popups/MyComponent";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("can change two values", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
  });
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const Modal = screen.getByRole("button", {
    name: /button/i,
  });
  await user.click(Modal);
  const nameInput = screen.getAllByRole("textbox", { name: "Name" })[0];
  const classInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
    name: "Type",
  });
  fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: "UwU" } });
  fireEvent.change(classInput, { target: { value: "kekw" } });
  expect(nameInput).toHaveValue("UwU");
  expect(classInput).toHaveValue("kekw");
});
```

The relevant portions of MyComponent are:

```js
const [classInput, setClassInput] = useState(defaultClassInput);

function updateInput(event, key, updateFunc) {
  updateFunc((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, [key]: event.target.value.trim() };
  });
}

<label htmlFor="name_class input">Name</label>
<label htmlFor="type input">
Type
</label>

<input
type="string"
onChange={(event) =>
updateInput(event, "name", setClassInput)
}
value={classInput.name}
id="name_class input"
/>

<input
type="string"
onChange={(event) =>
updateInput(event,"type",setClassInput)
}
value={classInput.type}
id="type input"
/>
```

The test fails, stating: "Expected the element to have value: kekw Recieved: " I have attempted to use userEvent.type but this result in only the first letter of the string that was passed being assigned as it's value despite being awaited. I have wrapped the fireEvent.change functions in `await act(async () => {})` but to no avail.

Comment: Could you please include the code for MyComponent

Comment: Where is your updateFunc defined?

Comment: Thanks for the response! updateFunc is the function that is passed as a parameter to updateInput

Comment: Im assuming updateInput isnt meant to be in there twice?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out, all I needed was npm update. It seems there was an error in the interaction between react testing library 12.1.5 and Jest